# Low volume while using Netflix Instant Play on a Mac

Tags: netflix

I'm experiencing very low volume on my MacBook Pro (running Snow Leopard) while using Netflix Instant Play. All of my other video sites are working fine, and my computer's volume is set to full. I've had the same problem on a Leopard MacBook Pro. Are there fixes within Netflix or for my computer itself that I can try?

Comment: I assume you've checked the volume slider within the Netflix playback window itself (I believe it's independent of the computer's main volume control.)

Comment: Yes. I've also checked the main volume control.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fine Mac program [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack) to amplify your entire system's volume while you watching Netflix, as described [here](http://lifehacker.com/127222/audio-hijack-pro-boost-your-volume).